Handle rate limiting headers from API in Spring RestClient?
I have an API that returns rate-limiting headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 1200
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 1199
X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 1609459200

I want to configure my RestClient to rate limit HTTP calls using this information and/or retry if the limit is exceeded.
Is there a way to achieve this using resilience4j or built-in mechanisms in Spring RestClient?

I guess you do not want to use RateLimiter.changeLimitForPeriod because this will only affect the limit for the next period and not the current one.

Maybe this question may help.
